# predict float number by neural network

Tags: python, pytorch, neural-network, prediction

I want to create a neural network to predict some outputs. two samples of data are here:

```
290,11,2,2700,14.7,43.7,77.6
320,2.1,2,2700,2.2,31.6,62.3
```

The first 4 columns are inputs and The last 3 columns are outputs.
I use torch. how many layers are needed for this problem. or what is best learning rate.
I create neural network with 4 layers as below:

```
self.fc1 = nn.Linear(4, 16)
self.fc2 = nn.Linear(16, 8)
self.fc3 = nn.Linear(8, 8)
self.fc4 = nn.Linear(8, 4)
self.fc5 = nn.Linear(4, 3)


x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
x = torch.relu(self.fc2(x))
x = torch.relu(self.fc3(x))
x = torch.relu(self.fc4(x))
x = self.fc5(x)
```

learning rate and epochs are:

```
lr=0.5
epoch=200000
```

But in training process Loss value stop in about 242 and it does not decrease.

```
Epoch 7000, Loss: 242.69976806640625
Epoch 7050, Loss: 242.69976806640625
Epoch 22730, Loss: 242.69976806640625
Epoch 22740, Loss: 242.69976806640625
Epoch 35600, Loss: 242.69976806640625
Epoch 35610, Loss: 242.69973754882812
Epoch 35620, Loss: 242.69976806640625
Epoch 35630, Loss: 242.69976806640625
Epoch 160260, Loss: 242.69973754882812
Epoch 160270, Loss: 242.69973754882812
Epoch 160280, Loss: 242.69973754882812
```

Others information are:

```
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use some activation layers to learn non-linear patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Your learning rate seems to be too large. You can try using a smaller lr for stable training. Also, try experimenting with more neurons in each layer or different activations like Sigmoid or Tanh (depends on the complexity of the data).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to overfit your network with few samples to see if your data is suitable for this type of network. And @Metro280's comment is quite true, you should lower your learning rate to about 1e-3 or 0.001, large learning rate can easily make your update overshoot the minima and actually go to infinity.